# What is the syntax to subscribe to an object's static event in PowerShell?

Tags: events, powershell, powershell-2.0

[Register-ObjectEvent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347672.aspx) looks for a object instance in the required parameter **InputObject**. What is the syntax for an object's static (*Shared*) event?

**UPDATE**: Correct syntax for [TimeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents_events.aspx):

```
$systemEvents = [Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents]
$timeChanged = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $systemEvents
-EventName 'TimeChanged' -Action { Write-Host "Time changed" }
```

Unfortunately, the SystemEvents will not be signaled in *PowerShell ISE*. Here's a sample using an object's staic event that works everywhere:

```
$networkInformation = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange];
$networkAddressChanged = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $networkInformation 
-EventName 'NetworkAddressChanged' 
-Action { Write-Host "NetworkAddressChanged event signaled" }
```

Comment: There is a message loop running in PowerShell, but you need to run as an admin to access it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you assign a static type to a variable, you can subscribe to static events.

For example:

```
$MyStaticType = [MyStaticNamespace.MyStaticClass]
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $MyStaticType -EventName MyStaticEvent -Action {Write-Host "Caught a static event"}
```

To find any static events a type may have, you can use Get-Member with the -Static switch

```
[MyStaticNamespace.MyStaticClass] | get-member -static -membertype event
```

**EDIT:**
I did notice when trying to access [Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents] events, that I needed to be running in an elevated prompt (on Vista and above) in order to access the messages.

Answer (score 3):

Steven's got the right answer so no need to vote on this (vote on his instead).  I just wanted to post a sample snippet that folks can use to play around with static events such that you don't have to find a BCL static event that's easy to fire.  :-)

```
$src = @'
using System;

namespace Utils {
public static class StaticEventTest 
{
    public static event EventHandler Fired;

    public static void RaiseFired()
    {
        if (Fired != null) 
        { 
            Fired(typeof(StaticEventTest), EventArgs.Empty); 
        }
    }
}}
'@

$srcId = 'Fired'

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $src

Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $srcId -ea 0

$id = Register-ObjectEvent ([Utils.StaticEventTest]) Fired `
          -SourceIdentifier $srcId -Action {"The static event fired"}

[Utils.StaticEventTest]::RaiseFired()

while (!$id.HasMoreData) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250 }

Receive-Job $id
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I took the liberty of borrowing much of the snippet in my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61264838/action-based-object-events-sometimes-lost).